# Convenient way to make new tuples/strings extended by 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

In part of a project, given a single integer/character x and a tuple/string a, I need to create a new tuple/string that's the original tuple/string extended by that element. My current code looks like:

```
def extend(x, a):
    if type(a) is tuple:
        return a + (x,)
    if type(a) is str:
        return a + x
```

Is there a better way to code this, to either make it shorter or more generalizable to data types?

Comment: Can you provide an example (sample tuple) and also the desired output?

Comment: Let's back up. Why do you need one function that has to determine if its argument is a string or a tuple?

Comment: `isinstance(a, tuple)` is preferable to `type(a) is tuple`, as it correctly handles subclassing.

Comment: I would have 2 functions here to chepners point

Comment: @chepner it's also slower when you're sure that `tuple` isn't subclassed

Comment: Even if you truly do need a function that will do this for both tuples and strings, perhaps it's short enough as is. It's fairly clear what it does-- no need to be too clever about it.

Comment: To some extent, you have to know before `extend` is called what the type of `a` is, because if it is a string, `x` also has to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ev Kounis use of a dictionary is original but if the aim was to gain speed, it doesn't really work, because the dictionary is rebuilt each time (`x` varies)

A slight modification would be to use a dictionary of *conversion functions*. This one is fixed.
Pass the parameter to the proper conversion function and it's done:

```
# this is built once
d = {tuple: lambda x:(x,), str: lambda x:x, list: lambda x:[x]}

def extend(x, a):
    return a + d[type(a)](x)
```

(which still doesn't work is passing a *subclassed* type of `str`, `tuple`, whatever, but if you're sure you won't, this works)

Honestly, using a dictionary for 3 keys won't be that fast, and a chain of `if`s is just as efficient.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear why you want to extend tuples and string at the same part of code. May be you need refactoring. `list` seems to be the correct type for such operations and it has already `.append(x)` for it.

If you are sure you need different types, you function seems OK. But just add

```
raise TypeError()
```

at the end of it. So you'll be sure not to miss unpredicted data type.

Comment: ... and return `None`

Comment: they should use `==` not `is`

Answer (score 3):

How about this way:

```
def extend(x, a):
    return a + {tuple: (x,), str: x, list: [x]}[type(a)]
```

Of course, keep in mind that the number of datatypes is really big and a *one-size-fits-all* approach does not exist.

So, take another hard look on whatever code comes before this and if you *really* need it, use this dictionary approach.

---

**EDIT**

- If you need to do this many many times, do it with an `if` block. As @chepner says, building a dictionary every time will render this approach too smart for its own good.
- If subclassing is also an issue, you should change from `type` to `isinstance` as @Jean-FrancoisFabre says.

Comment: would thoroughly appreciate a comment on that -1.

Comment: brave downvoters are a scarce thing. but the DV effect generally backfires when the provided solution works (like here)

Comment: I would add that subclasses of `tuple` and `str` and other fail when passed to your routine (`type(a)` would return the actual child type, unlike `isinstance`

Comment: No down vote, but it is a bit heavy: you have to create a new dict every time you the function is called, even though the actual value of `x` is irrelevant to the dict. You also have to create a tuple and a list whether they are needed or not.

Comment: Not my down vote, but this feels like an XY problem, they should use a mutable data structure in all likelihood and not create a method like this

Comment: yeah, DV punishes (tried to...) the fact that it's probably solving a XY problem.

Comment: Not my downvote either, but I think this would be done cleaner with a ternary if. I don't think OP's code can be made much better.